# Грамотный onUnLoad

Tags: javascript

Событие `onUnLoad` возникает если пользователь покидает страницу. Но к сожалению это поддерживается не во всех браузерах. Есть также вариант `onBeforeUnload`, но он вызывает нежелательное всплывающее окно. у меня стоит задача изменить JS переменную, в тот момент, когда пользователь покидает сайт или переходит на другую страницу. Есть ли какое-то кросс-браузерное решение?

Comment: какой смысл менять значение переменной, если браузер закрывается?

Comment: tcpack4, я написал для упрощения. В действительности там выполняется другая функция - завершение открытого longpoll запроса. Главное, это отлов события, когда пользователь покидает сайт или переходит на другую страницу.

Comment: так и спрашиваю, потому что реализация зависит от целей "других функций". но правда тут за исключением выше указанных ивентов, остается только метод через серверную часть: отправляете по интервалу запрос на сервер (ajax или websocket) о том, что у юзера с данной сессией (ID которых сгенерирован на сервере по уникальным данным) таб еще открыт. На сервере удаляете по дате старые записи.